# Is this correct by ardens lemma?

Tags: finite-automata

Just a small question. When applying Ardens lemma(X=RX+S=R*S) on the following..

E3 = 01* + 2E3 I understood it as either one of these but im quite unsure... 
E3 = 01*2* or is it E3 = 01* + 2*

Comment: Try reading it as `E3 = 2E3 + 01*`

Comment: E3 = 2*01*, but isn't that different from 01*2*?

Comment: It is, but `2E3+01*` is not different from `01*+2E3`. What does this tell you about your other attempts?
Neither "02" nor the empty string are accepted by E3 (but are by your first and second attempts respectively).

Comment: Aha I understand now! Thanks for the clarification.